# C and SDL issue with fopen_s

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a game, and I wanted to transition from hard coding positions for my objects to reading them from a text file. However I seem to be getting an unhandled exception, with this version of the code. I also had an issues when i tried to declare the FILE inside this function where it said that readData is being used but not initialized. I'd really appreciate some help in figuring out where I messed up. Thanks

```
void loadPlatform(gameState *gState) { // Platform load function
    fopen_s(gState->readData, "PlatformsLevel1.txt", "r");
    int tempPos;
    int i = 0;

    while (fscanf_s(gState->readData, "%d", &tempPos) > 0) {
        gState->posArray00[i] = tempPos;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(gState->readData);
```

Comment: I suggest you [read this `fopen_s` reference first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this has nothing to do with SDL. Should the tag be removed?

Comment: Did you get a compiler warning for the type mismatch on `fopen_s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you're missing a `&` in the call to fopen_s.

```
fopen_s(&gState->readData, "PlatformsLevel1.txt", "r");
```

The prototype for `fopen_s` is

```
errno_t fopen_s( 
    FILE** pFile,
    const char *filename,
    const char *mode 
);
```

The prototype for `fscanf_s` is

```
int fscanf_s( 
   FILE *stream,
   const char *format [,
   argument ]... 
);
```

If `gState->readData` is of type `FILE*`, and for this code to work, it should be, then you need to pass `&gState->readData` to `fopen_s`.